# JQuery auto updating hidden input

Tags: jquery, forms, input

I'm tying to update a hidden input with the value that is being inputed.

if you enter "Foo Bar" in the name text input box, I'd like the hidden item_name to become "Apply Fee to Foo Bar"

```
<input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="name" name="name" id="appendedInputButton" placeholder="Studnet's Name">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Next</button>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$("#name").on("keyup change", function() {
var value = this.value; 
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Apply Fee to ". $("#dom_element").text(value); /> 
});
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="name" name="name"  placeholder="Studnet's Name" />

<input id="myHidden" type="hidden" name="item_name"  /> 

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Next</button>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $("#name").on("keyup", function() {
     var value = $(this).val();
     $("#myHidden").val("Apply Fee to " + value); 
   });
 </script>
```

Comment: Sorry, it was in the original element that I copied

Answer (score 0):

Just a bit more readable for newbie :D

```
$('#name').on('keyup', function() {
    var hidden_input = $('#your_hidden');
    var prepend_txt = 'Apply Fee to';
    var name_val = $(this).val();
    hidden_input.val(prepend_txt+' '+name_val);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add the  tag like that inside the script code. You can see the debug console pressing F12 to see that's actually not valid. Something like this must do the trick:

```
<input type="text" id="studentname" class="input-xlarge" name="name" placeholder="Studnet's Name">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Next</button>
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="" id = "hiddeninput" />

<script type="text/javascript">
/* Trigger function when the #studentname input is changed */
$("#studentname").change(function() {
  /* Make the hidden input value be the value of the input, pre-pending the "Apply fee to " */
  $("#hiddeninput") . val("Apply Fee to " + $(this).val());
  });
 </script>
```

Notes:

1. Any html tag can only have 1 id, and the id must be unique in a page.
2. Javascript/jquery modifies the html. It doesn't display HTML on its own, so it makes no sense just writing a tag inside it.

Comment: I thank all of you, the code I checked worked, but it was Francisco's explanation that make sense.